# Stop windows installer from a webform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, installation, windows-installer

I have a windows installer for my windows service which opens a window form on install method. And the form has a cancel button which hides the form. On the same click I want to stop the installation and show a message as Installation interrupted.

Install code is

```html
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
        {
            base.Install(stateSaver);

                Form databaseSettings = new DatabaseSettings(this,stateSaver);
                databaseSettings.BringToFront();
                databaseSettings.TopMost = true;
                databaseSettings.ShowDialog(); 

        }
```

And Code for cancel button is

```html
 private void btnDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 this.Close();
}
```

Please let me know hoe to do this. An example code will be preffered.

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a Visual Studio custom action, so you throw an InstallException with the ctor that contains your error message and the install will roll back.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Install custom actions run after all the files are installed, that's why it rolls back and uninstalls everything. In addition, VS custom actions run in the execute sequence where you should not be showing UI, and anyone wanting a silent install will be out of luck. The right place to collect user input is in the UI sequence at the front, and if the canned VS dialogs are inadequate you should look at using another tool that lets you create dialogs in the UI sequence and validate them etc before the install starts.